# How to integrate by parts $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)}{1+x}dx$?

Tags: integration

I am asked to integrate this by part:

$$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)}{1+x}dx$$

My approach was to first notice that the upper part of the fraction equals to $\cos(2x)$, thus giving us:

$$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x}dx$$

For the integration by parts, I choose:

$$u(x)=\ln(1+x) \\u'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x} $$

$$v(x)=\cos(2x)\\ v'(x)=-2\sin(x) $$

Thus giving us:

$$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x}dx = \begin{bmatrix}
\ln(1+x)\cos(2x)
\end{bmatrix}_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}+2\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sin(2x)\ln(1+x)dx$$

But this just doesn't seem much easier. Any suggestions?

Comment: this integral has no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: You are just asked to integrate it by part, or to calculate?

Comment: @kolobokish I am asked to prove one inequality by using integration by parts on this integral.

Comment: So this is the inequality you should be asking here. At present, it is difficult to guess what you are really asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not use integration by parts, at first:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos^2\left(x\right)-\sin^2\left(x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x=\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos^2\left(x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x-\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x$$

Now:

1. $$\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos^2\left(x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{1}{1+x}\space\text{d}x+\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x\right\}$$
2. $$\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{1}{1+x}\space\text{d}x-\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x\right\}$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\int_{\text{n}\pi}^{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+x}\space\text{d}x$$

Substitute $\text{u}=2x$ and $\text{d}\text{u}=2\space\text{d}x$:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{2\text{n}\pi}^{2\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\text{u}\right)}{1+\frac{\text{u}}{2}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\int_{2\text{n}\pi}^{2\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\text{u}\right)}{2+\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}$$

Substitute $\text{s}=2+\text{u}$ and $\text{d}\text{s}=\text{d}\text{u}$:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\int_{2\left(1+\text{n}\pi\right)}^{2+2\left(1+\text{n}\right)\pi}\frac{\cos\left(\text{s}-2\right)}{\text{s}}\space\text{d}\text{s}$$